# How to populate a div with data from a json file that contains id of external html to add

Tags: html, json

I have a drop down box that when options are selected should populate a `div` below with the data from a raw html file containing only the selected option data.

The index file holds the dropdown, the json file holds the destinations which are `london`, `paris`, `new york` and `rome`, it also contains an `id` - the first three letters of the file name of the html file that corresponds to the option selected, e.g. `london-weather`, `paris-weather`, etc.

The idea is that user sees the drop down box, selects a city and then the json is checked for corresponding `id` to that city and places the html in that `id`'s file into the `div` below the dropdown box.

Here is the json file I have:

```
{
  "Destinations": [
  {
    "destinationName": "London",
    "destinationID": "lon"
  },
  {
    "destinationName": "New York",
    "destinationID": "nyc"
  },
  {
    "destinationName": "Paris",
    "destinationID": "par"
  },
  {
    "destinationName": "Rome",
    "destinationID": "rom"
  }]
}
```

My source html files, e.g. `lon_weather` (for london) - just consist of 2 `div`s that contain data from a weather app.

I have found an example [here](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/) that populates a second drop down box from the json file based on the selection, this is really close to what I want but it does not do the external html part and I cannot work out how to add the html part to it using the `id` found in the json file.